# How can I include side navbar when ngx-spinner is running? It only runs on the component where I put it

Tags: angular, ngx-spinner

````
```<div><ngx-spinner bdColor = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)" size = "medium" color = "#fff" type = "ball-spin" [fullScreen]="true"><p style="color: white" > Loading... </p></ngx-spinner><mat-card>```
````

[image]

I need to run the ngx-spinner including the sidebar.

Comment: might be opacity of your sidebar is higher than the loaders opacity.

Comment: can you please include ngx-spinner tag in app.component.html and try once?

Comment: Like says @AnantDhas, most of the time if you want this lib to cover the whole page, you can include in the main app template.

Comment: Thank you. Will try to add it in app.component.html.  @AnantDhas

Answer (score 2):

Actually, it has a built-in function so we put it in `app.component.html` where we can access it from anywhere.
Try to put it there.